# Randomly placing bitmaps in a grid on a custom view canvas?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view, android-bitmap

I am trying to take bitmap images from an ArrayList and randomly generate a grid of them to be used in a netwalk game. I have this method in another class separate to my GameView class:

```
public int getGridElem(int x, int y) {
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= mColumns || y >= mRows) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The coordinates (" + x + ", " + y + ") are not valid.");
    }
    return mGrid[gridPos(x, y)];
}
```

Im struggling to work out how to use this class to display a random grid of the images in the ArrayList?

Answer (score 0):

what about if you shuffle your ArrayList then create your gird ?!

Collections.shuffle(arrayList);